# How to perform background services, when application is not running state in iOS?

Tags: ios, background, apple-push-notifications

Edit: I have built up chat application. I want to update the local database, when, I receive notification in the app that time app is in not running state. 
I have implemented the following steps for push notification:

1)Implemented silent push notification.

2)Triggers the method "application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler" in background state of app.

3)But not triggers the method "didReceiveRemoteNotification" in the app When the app is terminated by the user. is it possible in the app to call this method? When, the app is not running the state?

Comment: You can't. One of the first things your app should do when it launches is update itself with the latest dats from your server.

Comment: You can use silent push notification to awake your app  in background. but if you use this frequently apple may reject your app

Comment: I have implemented silent push notification. But not trigger "application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler" method in my app (When the app is manually terminated by the user).  is it possible in app is manually closed by user? if yes, then how to implement it?